# SELECT statement optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not so expert in SQL queryes, but not even a complete newbie.
I'm exporting data from a MS-SQL database to an excel file using a SQL query.
I'm exporting many columns and two of this columns contain a date and an hour, this are the columns I use for the WHERE clause.
In detail I have about 200 rows for each day, everyone with a different hour, for many days. I need to extract the first value after the 15:00 of each day for more days.
Since the hours are different for each day i can't specify something like

```
SELECT a,b,hour,day FROM table WHERE hour='15:01'
```

because sometimes the value is at 15:01, sometimes 15:03 and so on (i'm looking for the closest value after the 15:00), for fix this i used this workaround:

```
SELECT TOP 1 a,b,hour,day FROM table WHERE hour > "15:00"
```

in this way i can take the first value after the 15:00 for a day...the problem is that i need this for more days...for a user-specifyed interval of days. At the moment i fix this with a `UNION ALL` statement, like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 a,b,hour,day FROM table WHERE data="first_day" AND hour > "15:00"
UNION ALL SELECT TOP 1 a,b,hour,day FROM table WHERE data="second_day" AND hour > "15:00"
UNION ALL SELECT TOP 1 a,b,hour,day FROM table WHERE data="third_day" AND hour > "15:00"
```

...and so on for all the days (i build the SQL string with a *for each* day in the specifyed interval).

Until now this worked, but now I need to expand the days interval (now is maximun a week, so 5 days) to up to 60 days. I don't want to build an huge query string, but i can't imagine an alternative way for write the SQL.

Any help appreciated

Ettore

Comment: Please tag your question with the query you are using.

Comment: Tell us which DBMS you are using. Also include the definition of all indexes on that table and the execution plan for your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typical solution for this uses `row_number()`:

```
SELECT a, b, hour, day
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY day ORDER BY hour) as seqnum
      FROM table t
      WHERE hour > '15:00'
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Really nice...i've not tryed this yet, but how do i specify the days interval? should add a `AND day > "start_day" AND day < "stop_day"` ?

Comment: @EttoreP . . . You should add that in the subquery (although it would also work in the outer query as well).